# Given a Data Type Name "Example String dataType = "Integer" check whether its a valid data type or not

Tags: java, data-structures, computer-science, type-conversion

Given a Data Type Name "Example String dataTypeString= "Integer" check whether its a valid data type or not.

I need to convert a simpleClassName (dataTypeString) to a valid class (Class type)and use it for the below function

```
public static boolean isValidType(Class<?> retType)
{
    if (retType.isPrimitive() && retType != void.class) return true;
    if (Number.class.isAssignableFrom(retType)) return true;
    if (AbstractCode.class.isAssignableFrom(retType)) return true;
    if (Boolean.class == retType) return true;
    if (Character.class == retType) return true;
    if (String.class == retType) return true;
    if (Date.class.isAssignableFrom(retType)) return true;
    if (byte[].class.isAssignableFrom(retType)) return true;
    if (Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(retType)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Class c = Class.forName("com.package.MyClass");

Comment: @AmirAfghani yeah but a simple class name would look like "MyClass", without package

Comment: @LucaNegrini ok, and?  If the OP can't figure that out they will have bigger problems

Comment: @AmirAfghani ya thats the challenging part here.

Comment: Please elaborate on what is challenging about using that method, and we can respond.

Comment: i am actually using an external library  FastClasspathScanner which helps me to do all the work similar to reflect in java but its very efficient . So instead of **Field** data type in REFLECT , there is **FieldInfo** in FastClasspathScanner . so to get the data type of the field its FieldInfo eachFieldInfo;    eachFieldInfo.getTypeStr(); which returns the string type ie "Integer"

Comment: https://github.com/lukehutch/fast-classpath-scanner